# Auto Filter Code Works on Its Own but Not With Rest of Macro - Runtime Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofilter

I am trying to auto filter to delete all rows that contain the value of 0.  The code works on its own (it's the last bit at the bottom), but when I add it to my bigger macro, I get

> runtime error 1004

The problem seems to be with the line:

```
Set VRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("b1"), ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown))
```

But I can't figure out how to change it to still achieve what I want (and keep it simple so I can reuse it for other sheets without having to change/specify the sheet name a bunch of times)

Any help would be appreciated - I'm stuck.  Thanks guys!

```
Sub Test()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    ' Add a heading to the “GL” column

    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GL"

    'Create new worksheets for each heading (with heading names)

    Dim xRg As Excel.Range
    Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
    Set wSh = ActiveSheet
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In wSh.Range("D2:P2")
        With wBk
            .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
            If Err.Number = 1004 Then
              Debug.Print xRg.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next xRg

    'Copies the master sheet values into new worksheet called “Test”
    '(that was created with the code above based on the header name in row 2),
    ' and deletes inapplicable columns

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Sheets("Test").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Test").Range("A1").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

        If ActiveCell.Value = "Test" _
            Or ActiveCell.Value = "GL" Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

        Else

            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Selection.End(xlUp).Select

        End If
    Loop

    ' THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK WITH REST OF MACRO BUT WORKS ON ITS OWN
    ' Removes 0 values and total row

    Sheets("Test").Activate
    Dim VRange As Range

    Set VRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("b1"), ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown))

    With VRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code works on its own (it's the last bit at the bottom), but when
>   I add it to my bigger macro, ...

that's because your *bigger macro* does things before the "standalone" code that this latter is unaware of and therefore cannot handle

for example

- the code lines

  ```
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
  Sheets("Test").Activate
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
  Sheets("Test").Range("A1").Select
  ```

  are copying "Sheet1" `UsedRange` and pasting to "Test" sheet starting at cell A1

  hence you are heavily relying on actual "structure" of "Sheet1" sheet, i.e. you're assuming that its `UsedRange` will have its upper-right corner in some well known (for you, only) cell
- the  `Do Until ... Loop` loop is deleting "Test" sheet columns in relation to the content of its first row cells starting from A1

  should there be no cells with "Test" or "GL" content then all "Test" sheet relevant (i.e. with not empty cell in row 1) columns would be deleted!
- in relation to the above two issues, `Set VRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("b1"), ActiveSheet.Range("b1").End(xlDown))` could very well reference "Test" sheet whole empty column B!

In the end, to really help you you should enhance your code (and your post, too) with your possible "Sheet1" data "structure" handling

and also, consider abandoning all that `Select/Activate/Selection/ActiveXXX` coding pattern, since it'll take you to quickly loose control over what's your code actually doing

Trying to help you in a possible refactoring of your code, you may consider the following one (explanation in comments):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xRg As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'reference "Sheet1" sheet
        .Range("C2").Value = "GL" ' Add “GL” column heading to referenced sheet "C2" cell

        'Create new worksheets for each heading (with heading names)
        With .Range("D2:P2") 'reference referenced sheet range "D2:P2"
            Select Case True
                Case WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0  'if only empty cells in referenced range
                    MsgBox "no values in " & .Address(False, False)
                    Exit Sub
                Case .Find("test", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing
                    If Not IsSheetAlreadyThere("Test") Then
                        MsgBox "no 'Test' sheet neither in " & .Address(False, False) & " nor already in " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " workbook"
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        Sheets("Test").UsedRange.ClearContents
                    End If
            End Select


            For Each xRg In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'loop through referenced range not empty cells only
                If IsSheetAlreadyThere(xRg.Value) Then ' if current cell value matches an existent sheet name
                    Sheets(xRg.Value).UsedRange.ClearContents ' clear the content of the existent sheet named after current cell value
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next ' handle possible errors due to invalid sheet names
                    Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = xRg.Value 'add a new sheet and try naming it after current cell value
                    If Err.Number = 1004 Then ' if naming new sheet failed
                        Debug.Print "Name '" & xRg.Value & "' not a valid worksheet name"
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                        ActiveSheet.Delete 'deelete new sheet
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            Next
        End With ' stop referencing "Sheet1" sheet rang "D2:P2"

        'Copies the master ("Sheet1") sheet values into new worksheet called “Test”
        '(that was created with the code above based on the header name in row 2),
        ' and deletes inapplicable columns
        With .UsedRange 'reference referenced sheet (i.e. "Sheet1") "used" range
            Sheets("Test").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value ' copy paste its values in "Test" sheet starting from this latter A1 cell
        End With

    End With ' stop referencing "Sheet1" sheet

    With Sheets("Test") ' reference "Test" sheet
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) = 0 Then  'if only empty cells in reference sheet (i.e. "Test") row 1
            MsgBox "no values in " & .Address(False, False)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim f As Range
        Set f = .UsedRange.Cells(1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) ' set f as a "dummy" cell out of used range
        For Each xRg In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'loop through referenced sheet row 1 cells from column 1 rightwards to last not empty one
            Select Case xRg.Value ' query curent cell value
                Case "Test", "GL" ' if it's a "good" name then do nothing
                Case Else ' if it's a "bad" name then add current cell to the ones whose entirecolumn is to be deleted
                    Set f = Union(f, xRg)
            End Select
        Next
        Set f = Intersect(.UsedRange, f) ' get rid of the "dummy" cell
        If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireColumn.Delete 'if any found cell with "bad" names then delete their entire column

        With .Range("B1", .Range("b1").End(xlDown)) '  <<<< hope that there's actually some data in column "B" !!>>>>
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        With Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange) 'reference referenced sheet column A cells in used range (avoid considering one million rows)
            MsgBox .Address
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End With ' stop referencing "Test" sheet

End Sub

Function IsSheetAlreadyThere(shtName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsSheetAlreadyThere = Sheets(shtName).Name = shtName
End Function
```

> I am trying to auto filter to delete all rows that contain the value
>   of 0

Other than the `AutoFilter()` approach you could use this other one:

```
With Sheets("Test")
    With .Range("b1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) <<<< hope that there's actually some data in column "B" !!>>>>
        .Replace What:=0, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With 
End With
```